# What is it that makes wallet unique across multiple wallet providers?

Tags: wallets

So there are multiple wallet providers for example metamask, exodus, ...

I'm not able to understand what is it that makes wallet unique across all providers?

Comment: What do you mean "unique"? Nothing stops you from using the same private key for multiple wallets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you talk about your personal wallet what you mean is an address on the Blockchain (or rather, a public key that is connected to your private key) that looks like this `0x342n1b11...` . On the certain blockchain there is only one such address and it may contain many tokens and coins that are built on this blockchain. You can see it on Ethscan or BSCscan or whichever chain you use.

What those wallet providers do is they take this address of yours and give it a nice UI, allow you to connect to dApps and write dApps using their APIs. Some also provide neat security features. But the address on the blockchain is still the same for you on all of the wallets so the tokens that it shows are the same too.

You can easily create a new wallet address that is going to be empty, of course.

Comment: You mean I can have 1 wallet address (public key and private key pair, say on blockchain network ethereum)  and that can be used across all wallets like metamask, exodus, etc?

Comment: Yes, this is right. Make sure to "import" your wallet when you want to open it on the certain wallet provider. "Import" just means that instead of creating a new wallet you want to enter your private key from already existing wallet.

Comment: And is there any way by which I can be assured that the screen on which I am entering the private key (import) will not misuse my key?

Comment: You should never give your private key to any dApp or wallet that you are not 100% sure in. As the matter of fact, it is a common scammer tactic - to create copies of popular wallets that look the same, but just steal your private key.

Comment: Ok on what basis then do we trust things like metamask, exodus?